# Possible bug with Run postinstall?

Tags: inno-setup

I have set to display the checkbox "Run MyApp.exe" at the end of the installation:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; Flags: postinstall; Description: "Start MyApp (recommended)"
```

But with this option, Setup does NOT CLOSE after MyApp has been started with the above option. Only when I close MyApp then Setup closes too! Is this a bug?

So how can Setup be closed when MyApp has been started with the above option?

Comment: With your script, I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe. For me an installer closes as expected. Post a log file showing the behavior you describe.

Comment: The problem was solved by using my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

By using the flag `nowait`.

From the documentation:

> nowait: If this flag is specified, it will not wait for the process to
>   finish executing before proceeding to the next [Run] entry, or
>   completing Setup.

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; Flags: postinstall nowait; Description: "Start MyApp (recommended)"
```

Comment: By *"Setup does NOT CLOSE"*, did you mean that the installer window does not close? Or that installer process does not finish?